# How to add nuget package source with \\foldername\filename path in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I have to add nuget package source with path \foldername\filename. I have followed the steps:
1. Tools->Options->Nuget Package Manager->Package Sources, there I added new package source with path  \foldername\filename but it is giving error that "path could not resolved".
I have to access packages from this path format.

Can anyone tell where I am wrong or anything is missing in this?